# Inferred generics of class methods

Tags: typescript

I've created this simple example, is there a nicer way of doing something like this so at the end `getProp` can return out a correctly inferred type? Right now passing in 3 type arguments is a bit unwieldy.

```
  public async getProp<
    T extends Record<string, any>,
    K extends Extract<keyof T, string>,
    V extends T[K]
  >(prop: K): Promise<V | undefined> {
    const result: Partial<T> = await this.getProps<T>([prop]);

    return result?.[prop];
  }

  private async exampleUsage() {
    // How it needs to be used
    const result1 = await this.getProp<{ foo: Date; bar: number }, 'foo', Date>(
      'foo'
    );

    // How I'd like it to be used
    const result2 = await this.getProp<{ foo: Date; bar: number }>('foo');
  }
```

Comment: You did not define `getProps`. Please share reproducible example

Comment: Could you also add a class that wraps these methods?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I don't need to define get props because you can see based on the type of result what will be returned, I specifically did this rather than relying on inferred typing so you can see what will be contained in result.

Comment: @Terminat, good suggestion and that's ultimately the best way I found of handling it.